# How to write a function with symbolic vectors as arguments in sympy?

Tags: python, sympy

I want to write a function in sympy that takes as arguments two symbolic vectors and returns their inner product, e.g:

```
import sympy as sy
sy.init_printing()
phi = sy.symbols("phi")
v1 = sy.Matrix([sy.cos(phi),sy.sin(phi),0])
v2 = sy.Matrix([-sy.sin(phi),sy.cos(phi),0])
```

How do I declare a function:

```
fun = sy.Function("fun")
```

of two arguments like `v1,v2` that returns their inner product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write this kind of functions just like ordinary Python functions. Whenever a SymPy object is encountered in an operation, the rest of the functions are automatically converted to SymPy equivalents.

`sy.Function` is for unknown functions, for example when involved in differential equations.

```py
import sympy as sy
phi = sy.symbols("phi")
v1=sy.Matrix([sy.cos(phi),sy.sin(phi),0])
v2=sy.Matrix([-sy.sin(phi),sy.cos(phi),0])
v3=sy.Matrix([sy.cos(phi),sy.sin(phi),0])
v4=sy.Matrix([sy.sin(phi),sy.cos(phi),0])

def fun(v1, v2):
    assert isinstance(v1, sy.Matrix) and v1.shape[1] == 1
    assert isinstance(v2, sy.Matrix) and v2.shape[1] == 1 and v1.shape == v2.shape
    return sy.simplify(sum([v1[i]*v2[i] for i in range(v1.shape[0])])

print (fun(v1, v2))
print (fun(v1, v1))
print (fun(v3, v4))
```

Outputs:

```
0
1
2*sin(phi)*cos(phi)
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I figured as much. I wrote:
'av=sy.MatrixSymbol('av',3,1)
bv=sy.MatrixSymbol('bv',1,3)


def f1fun(av,bv,f1):
    f1=  sy.transpose(av)*bv
    return f1'
which seems to be working fine

Comment: You should remove `f1` as last parameter of `f1fun`

Comment: it seems my function returns a (1,1) array and not a scalar?

Comment: Just take element [0][0] of that matrix.  As in `return f1[0][0]`.  You implemented it as a matrix product, so it's a logical the result is a matrix.

Comment: thanks @JohanC for ther help. 
You are right I implemented it as a matrix.
I also want a function to return the cross product. I see that the package sympy.physics.vector has a cross product but you have to define all vectors on a reference frame. I am reluctant to try it for some reason

Comment: No, `av=sy.Symbol('av') ` is not needed. If `av` gets a value as result of sympy operations its automatically a sympy symbol.

Comment: Better also add `simplify` as in `return sy.simplify(f1[0][0])` to your function. Otherwise sympy keeps expressions in an unsimplified form.

Comment: `return sy.simplify(f1[0][0])`

Comment: so my code is:
    `def f1fun(av,bv): 
        return sy.simplify(sy.transpose(av)*bv)[0,0]`
and gives the right answer

Comment: Yes, a very pythonic way to write it.